# Display only few div and hide all other div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a main div `<div id="divMain">`, under which I've multiple divisions. But, I'm trying to display only few div's say `<div id="div3"> & <div id="div4">` and hide other inside divMain. I'm not getting it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:not` selector to filter out hiding few elements using their selector:

```
$('#divMain div:not(#div3,#div4)').hide();
```

In case you have inner divs in div3 and div4, you can use:

```
$('#divMain div:not("#div3,#div4,#div3 *,#div4 *")').hide();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XQ2xe/2/)**

Comment: This is it, was just typing it up in a comment.

Comment: Its working in fiddle, but I don't know whats wrong in the code

Comment: @NizamAli: have you tried the second approach. also where have you written the code. It should be there after this DOM is loaded??

Comment: Thanks.. But I tried with $('#divMain').show().siblings('div.msg').hide();

Answer (score 2):

First hide all `div` in `divMain` and then show the few you want using the [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$('#divMain div').hide();
$('#div3, #div4').show();
```

Comment: Thanks.. let me check

Comment: Click the run button to test, it is working, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/95qE8/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#div1, #div2" ).hide();
```

It supports multiple DOM elements.

Comment: I can't say that only div1 and div2 would be there. There might tens or hundres of div's

Comment: That was just an example, I was trying to explain you that jQuery's hide supports multiple objects, so you can pass in as many objects as you can to hide / show.

Comment: No..I should not give all 100 div's inside it, rather I should show only selected and hide the other.